# Find a design matrix giving a prescribed covariance matrix

Tags: estimation, pca, linear-algebra, multivariate-normal-distribution

Given a symmetrical positive-definite matrix $L$, how do I find a matrix $X$ such that $L = X^T X$?

Comment: This isn't really on-topic, but [the Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) is typically the most convenient.

Comment: It is not possible to recover design matrix $X$ from the product $X^TX$, without any additional information, since for any orthogonal matrix $O$, the product $(OX)^T(OX)=X^TX$ does not change.

Comment: @Dougal What is the reason you think this question is not on-topic here?

Comment: @whuber I somehow missed the title of the question in the review page, and thought it was purely a linear algebra question. With the edited title it's clearer that it's appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, you can reverse the principal components process.

Let's start by making some uncorrelated, centered and normalized data, you can create the columns in your matrix by drawing from any distribution as long as the draws are independent.  Here I draw from a centered and standardized uniform distribution $X \sim U(-.5, .5) / \sqrt{12}$, but only because it is convenient and illustrates the process:

```
> X <- matrix(runif(120000, -.5, .5)/ (1/sqrt(12)), 
              nrow=40000)
> t(X) %*% X / 400000
              [,1]          [,2]          [,3]
[1,]  0.0996386570 -0.0002036308 -0.0006817355
[2,] -0.0002036308  0.1000222332  0.0015659048
[3,] -0.0006817355  0.0015659048  0.1000916918
```

That is:

$$ \frac{1}{N} X^t X = I$$

Now let's write down a symmetric, positive definite matrix that we want to be our final correlation matrix:

```
S <- matrix(c(  1, -.5,   0,
              -.5,   1, -.5,
                0, -.5,   1), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE
)
```

Use the `sqrtm` function to compute the matrix square root:

```
> rtS <- sqrtm(S)
> t(rtS) %*% rtS
              [,1] [,2]          [,3]
[1,]  1.000000e+00 -0.5  5.551115e-17
[2,] -5.000000e-01  1.0 -5.000000e-01
[3,]  5.551115e-17 -0.5  1.000000e+00
```

Then form the matrix product $X\sqrt{S}$.  This has the property that:

$$ (X\sqrt{S})^t X\sqrt{S}  = \sqrt{S}^t X^t X \sqrt{S} = N \sqrt{S}^t \sqrt{S} = NS $$

so

$$ \frac{1}{N} (X\sqrt{S})^t (X\sqrt{S}) = S $$

so $X \sqrt{S}$ is the data matrix you want

```
> t(X %*% sqrtm(S)) %*% (X %*% sqrtm(S)) / 40000
             [,1]       [,2]         [,3]
[1,]  0.998555833 -0.4987640 -0.009608847
[2,] -0.498764047  0.9921826 -0.483641573
[3,] -0.009608847 -0.4836416  0.993164671
```